# Bash script to edit file name, and move the file.

Tags: linux, bash, file-management

I've some music that is all named `1 - (song author) - (song name).flac` and I want to change the file name to just `(song author) - (song name).flac` then move it to a directory. Heres what I have so far:

```
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
 cp $line /home/user/Desktop/Music/$(cut -c3- "$line");
done < filelist.txt
```

filelist.txt contains a list of files that I want renamed and moved.

It doesn't work, but in a way I thought was interesting. I get the error `bash: /bin/cp: Argument list too long`, and after examining the contents of `line` after the cut, it just looks like random characters/character codes. Could someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show the `$line`?  Where did filelist originate, perhaps it is unicode?

Comment: Also, the files are in the current folder according to this script.  What criteria was used for them to be included in filelist.txt (there may be a way to do this without the file list).

Comment: filelist.txt was created with `ls || grep flac > filelist.txt`. I rather wouldn't include contents of `$line`. It is exactly like the contents of `/dev/random`

Comment: @btf1998 I'm afraid you did not create that file this way. What your command says: "run ls and only if it fails (almost never, called this way), run grep that looks for "flac" in stdin and write the output to filelist.txt". That is filelist.txt must have been created BEFORE you ran this command, by some other method. My guess would be: you copied one of the flacs somehow.

Comment: small typo, `ls | grep flac > filelist.txt` was actually how the file was created.

Answer (score 0):

`cut` uses a file, or stdin, and the switch -c is for characters and you most likely want fields instead, with space separators. Also, you have to enclose cp's second argument in quotes. And you need to specify -c5- to get rid of the :

```
while read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
  cp $line "/home/user/Desktop/Music/$(echo "$line" | cut -d ' ' -f3-)"
done < filelist.txt
```